# Android Spinner not Showing DropDown menu

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I am trying to display a spinner in **FrameLayout** but it's not showing the drop down menu. i am unable to find the issue.

> XML

```
 <FrameLayout
//design continue here
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#5b89ff"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>`
```

> Code

```
final List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();

    list.add("jamshaid");
    list.add("jamshaid");
    list.add("jamshaid");
    list.add("jamshaid");
    list.add("jamshaid");

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

> My onCreate method

```
TabHost host; 
host = findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    spinner= findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
    host.setup();
    //Tab 1
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = host.newTabSpec("News Feed");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    spec.setIndicator("News Feed");
    host.addTab(spec);`
```

## Update 1

Using RelativeLayout instead FrameLayout throws
`android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout`

Comment: Check out thsi link : https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/

Comment: @akshay tried that as well

Comment: make linear layout height wrap_content

Comment: @akshay not working

Comment: @Nancy Please check given link

Comment: Its casting Error, you have cast FrameLayout with RelativeLayout, please check where you have done findViewById of FrameLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line and check,

```
arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); //Comment this line
```

> **Try this change also :**
>
> ```
> ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
>             android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list); //Changed layout resource id
> ```

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of your app screen to check layout of your spinner. May be code is okay but spinner is not showing from xml.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
final List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();

    list.add("jamshaid");
    list.add("jamshaid");
    list.add("jamshaid");
    list.add("jamshaid");
    list.add("jamshaid");

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this: 
code:

```
public class MainClass extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addOnSpinner();
}

private void addOnSpinner() {

    Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add("A");
    list.add("B");

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

**XML:**

```
<FrameLayout
//layout
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```